# Is there a way to download file in R from a "blob" url?

Tags: r, blob

first-time poster here so please let me know if my formatting is off.

I'm trying to automate some data collection I do weekly via R. To do this I download data from the appropriate URL in Rscript and for 10/11 datasets my code is fine. My holdup is downloading data from the below blob URL. Currently, I am downloading all other files with the download.file command but have found no alternatives in base R or in packages for blob URLs. Is there a method for downloading "blob" files from R onto my computer?

doc <- "blob:[https://covid.cdc.gov/3227d54b-d64d-4e03-be5a-a872a1c2025c"](https://covid.cdc.gov/3227d54b-d64d-4e03-be5a-a872a1c2025c%22)

I've tried running the above URL through download.file and shortening the above URL to the section following "blob:" with no luck.

A basic example of the code I am currently using:

`download.file(doc,doc_path)`

I really have no particular understanding of the core structure of "blob" URLs so if I am fundamentally misunderstanding something please let me know.

As a note I think the AzureStor package might be useful but haven't determined how to use it appropriately.

Any info is much appreciated.

Comment: Blob URLs refer to data that's stored locally in your web browser's memory, presumably created from executing JavaScript functions. That's not data that R can download directly. You'd need to interact with something that can run and execute javascript, like the RSelenium package. But even then since blobs can hold arbitrary bytes of data, it's unclear exactly how to properly decode the blob bytes into any usable form unless you know exactly how it was created.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for the info, this sheds some light on the subject for me. From what you said it sounds like I might get lucky with RSenelium but it is unlikely to work in the aggregate of cases. Do you think it is generally more effective to just manually download blob URLs when working in R?